# moment-generating function is well defined

Tags: probability-theory, moment-generating-functions

Let $X$ be a random variable, $t \in R, M_X(t) = E(exp(t*i*X))$ the moment-generating function.
Proof that $M_X$ is well defined.

I assume I have to proof that if the random variables $X_1$ and $X_2$ have the same distribution, then $E(exp(t*i*X_1)) = E(exp(t*i*X_2))$ should hold.
But I don't know how to show it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. This is normally called the [characteristic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_(probability_theory)).
2. It wants you to show that $E(\exp{(itX)})$ is *finite* for any probability distribution. This amounts to
   $$ \lvert E(e^{itX}) \rvert = \left| \int_{\Omega} e^{itx} dP(x) \right| \leq \int_{\Omega} \lvert e^{itx} \rvert \, dP(x) \leq \int_{\Omega} 1 \, dP(x) = 1. $$

Comment: Thank you for helping me! One question: How should I have known I had to proof the finiteness?

Comment: I think this is likely a slightly sloppy use of the term to mean "definition gives a sensible output for every input". Sensible here meaning finite. It's conventional, anyway: one can also speak of a well-defined output (and I almost did two sentences ago, before I caught myself).

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot!